# C# already ordered list by two values, need to compare

Tags: c#, .net

I have an ordered list ordered by two values. It contains a string, a TimeSpan and a integer. Its ordered by the the two first. I'll show you an example of what it contains:

```
E2801160600002066ED71483 09:36:37.6367671 1
E2801160600002066ED71483 09:36:38.1968231 1
E2801160600002066ED71483 09:36:38.8968931 2
E2801160600002066ED71483 09:36:39.4969531 2
E2801160600002066ED71483 09:36:40.2020236 2
E2801160600002066ED71493 09:36:37.6367671 2
E2801160600002066ED71493 09:36:38.3968431 2
E2801160600002066ED71493 09:36:39.0969131 1
```

The last integer refers to two antenas, number one is first antenna and number two is the second. It will always go in a direction, I mean if it goes first for the number one and later for the number two, it means the product is going outside. If it goes first for the number two and later for the number one, it means the product is going inside.

So I need to know how to iterate the list and compare the integer to know if the product is going outside or inside.

In the example the first product (string ends in 83) is going outside and the second product (string ends in 93) is going inside. So you know what I mean.

Comment: Could you please provide the definition of the list's type? How are the properties called that store the `string`, the `Timespan` and the `int`. This will make answering easier.

Comment: Create a class to hold these values, separate and parse the strings and populate the class with these values, then iterate over the list to determine what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your model looks like so:

```
class Data
{
    string ProductId {get; set;}
    Timespan Timespan {get; set;}
    int Antenna {get; set;}
}
```

With your sorted list...

```
List<Data> data = ...
```

...do the following with the help of Linq: First group it by product...

```
var productEntries = data.GroupBy(entry => entry.ProductId);
```

...then project the product groupings to a new list (`IEnumerable`, really) and determine whether the product is incoming our outgoing by checking if the first item of the group has the antenna ID 1 or 2.

```
var productDirections = productEntries.Select(
    product => new
        {
            Id = product.Key,
            IsIncoming = product.First().Antenna == 2
        });
```

Afterwards you can iterate over the new list and check the `IsIncoming` boolean to get the direction of a product.

```
foreach (var product in productDirections)
{
    if (product.IsIncoming)
        handleIncoming(product.Key);
    else
        handleOutgoing(product.Key);
}
```

Comment: Your solution works nice when both antennas recognize the tag. But now I have a new problem. When only the first antenna reads it, then it says the product is going outside and when only the second antenna reads it, then it says its going inside. And thats not valid, because when its only read by the first antenna the product is still inside and when its only read by the second, the product is still outside. Thanks for your help anyway I hope you can help me and thanks a lot really!

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Do you mean the antenna ID `int` can be empty? Could you update your example lines above with those cases?

Comment: I fixed it, I mean if the object is only read by the antenna number 2, the product is still outside and its not incoming. And if the product is only read by the antenna number 1, the product is still inside and its not outgoing. See my new answer to see the fix.

Answer (score 1):

To Abbondanza, thanks for your help man

```
var productDirection = productEntries.Select(
                    product => new
                        {
                            Product = product.Key,
                            IsIncoming = product.First().antena == 2 && product.Last().antena == 1,
                            IsOutgoing = product.First().antena == 1 && product.Last().antena == 2,
                            StillInside = product.First().antena == 1
                        });

                foreach (var product in productDirection)
                {
                    if (product.IsIncoming)
                    {
            // handle incoming products
                        Console.WriteLine("The product " + product.Product + " is incoming");
                    }

                    else if (product.IsOutgoing)
                    {
                        // handle outgoing products
                        Console.WriteLine("The product " + product.Product + " is outgoing");
                    }
                    else if (product.StillInside)
                    {
            //handle still inside products
                        Console.WriteLine("The product " + product.Product + " is still inside");
                    }
                    else
                    {
            //handle still outside products
                        Console.WriteLine("The product " + product.Product + " is still outside");
                    }

                }
```