# RFID app for logistic application - Mercury API

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get some opinions about how I can resolve a problem. I'm making a .NET application (wpf) using the RFID technology. The reader is a ThingMagic Astra-EX and it uses the Mercury API.

The purpose of the app is to control what products go inside or outside of my company's warehouse.

I have the reader which does have an integrated antenna and also have and external antenna. So with both of them, I can know what antenna reads first the tags and what reads last so I can know if the products go inside or outside.

Well once explained, now I need what should be the best solution in the code to do it. I thought about reading during some seconds adding tag objets to a list with the antenna info. Then group the list by tag ID and then select the first antenna which read it and then the last so I can know if they go inside or outside. But I think I can lose data while it processes the info and start to read again and some tags couldnt be read. And also the specified time to read is undetermined and I think it can cause problems if you go inside and outside fast with the products etc.

So, I need to know how to control it so I can always be sure what products are going inside and what outside.

Obviously I already have a database for the products and the registry about inside or outside operations.

Comment: I let you here another question I made so you can maybe understand better this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132429/c-sharp-already-ordered-list-by-two-values-need-to-compare/37132792?noredirect=1#comment61806762_37132792

Comment: The simple solution is to add bar codes to locations in the warehouse.  Then when scan is made read the location and then the product.  At work we have a portable book of bar codes that user scans specifying type of operation.  So a different operating can be received , moved location, shipped.

Comment: Thats not really a solution in this case, I am not the leader so I have to made it just with this material, the reader, the external antenna, the tags and the app :)